# Docker ROS "unable to communicate with master!"

Tags: ros, docker, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have ros indigo running through docker and when i try to run rostopic list on a new terminal with roscore open in another, I get "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!" I don't really have experience with any of this but both of these terminals are on the same laptop so I'm unsure as to what the problem could be or what to do,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254269/docker-ros-%22unable-to-communicate-with-master!%22/) by [entombedstorm](https://answers.ros.org/users/29314/entombedstorm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to fix this by typing ip addr and noting the ip address of the machine I was using.

After finding the IP, edit the /etc/hosts file with that IP and your hostname, which can be found in the /etc/hostname file.

(I had to add 127.17.0.2 9fc279ddb197 to my hosts file)

---

Originally posted by [Mabecr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29986/mabecr/) with karma: 51 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2020-07-08**:
I already have the IP and hostname in my `/etc/hosts` file but I still have the problem `ERROR: Unable to communicate with master`

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2020-07-08**:
Actually I exited from my docker container, logged back in, and it is working now. I have two terminals, on my laptop: ter1 in which the ROS application is running and ter2 in which I can do `rostopic list` and see all the topics. I have in my `/etc/hosts` file what @Mabecr suggested.